# Error sending message from Twilio-issued toll-free number in trial mode

Tags: twilio, verification

I'm trying to test my integration in a trial mode using a Twilio-issued toll-free number. Sending the message to my mobile number that I've verified in the console.

The messages are not delivered and the log says: 30032 Toll-Free Verification Required.

Is this the intended behavior? I was under the impression that the message to the verified number should be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the onboarding process but even in trial mode toll-free phone numbers must be verified before you'll be able to send out SMS message. Contact Twilio support to take care of the verification.